# when i am trying to run mupx deploy it is showing error

Tags: javascript, json, meteor, digital-ocean, mup

**error in console**

shubhabrata@shubhabrata-VirtualBox:~/Meteor/myapp$ mupx deploy

### Meteor Up: Production Quality Meteor Deployments

Configuration file : mup.json
Settings file      : settings.json

“ Checkout Kadira!
  It's the best way to monitor performance of your app.
  Visit: https://kadira.io/mup ”

Meteor app path    : /home/shubhabrata/Meteor/myapp
Using buildOptions : {}
buffer.js:80
      throw new Error(
      ^

Error: If encoding is specified then the first argument must be a string
    at new Buffer (buffer.js:80:13)
    at Readable. (/usr/lib/node_modules/mupx/node_modules/archiver/lib/util/index.js:32:15)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at Readable.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:975:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)

Comment: I am getting the same error

Comment: did you get any solution?

Comment: yes i started using mup instead of mupx and downgraded my node to from 6 to 5.

Comment: thanks for the information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching from node 7 to node 5.12 worked for me. I installed using nvm so that I can use later node versions in the future.

This occurred for me while using (deliberately) an old version of mup. It could well be that just upgrading mup will fix the problem.